# Linux how to stop ROS script that starts after reboot

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, virtualbox, xterm

I've created a script that would check whether a certain server is running and restart it in event of crash (the script runs endlessly every 10 seconds).

> I cannot run any commands and CTRL+C, CTRL+A, CTRL+Z do NOT work.

The main problem is also that the machine server is not running so the IP is not reachable with MobaXterm.

Is there another workaround to stop/ignore/break the script?

> I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox with only Terminal, no GUI!

In case it helps, here are the scripts.

The RestartScript:

```
#! /bin/bash
while :
do
        COUNT="$(pgrep -f Odie | wc -l)"
        echo $'\n'
        echo "Number of Odie processes (COUNT) = $((COUNT))"
        echo "$(pgrep -fla Odie)"

        case "$(screen -ls | grep Odie | wc -l)" in
        0) echo "Restarting Odie:       $(date)" | sudo tee -a /var/log/OdieLog.txt
        bash -c "exec -a OnlyOdie ./screen_start.sh"
        ;;
        1) # all ok
        echo "Process is running:       $(date)" | sudo tee -a  /var/log/OdieLog.txt
        ;;
        2) echo "Removed double Odie:   $(date)"  | sudo tee -a /var/log/OdieLog.txt
        #kill $(pgrep -f OnlyOdie | awk '{print $1}')
        screen -ls | awk -vFS='\t|[.]' '/Odie/ {system("screen -S "$2" -X quit")}'
        ;;
        esac
sleep 10
done
```

screen_start.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
SCREEN_COUNT="$(screen -ls | grep Odie | wc -l)"

if [ "$SCREEN_COUNT" -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "SCREEN_COUNT = ZERO"
        screen -sdm ./start.sh -S Odie
fi
```

Sadly I can not add the ROS file content since I can not access it.

Comment: Could you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/439912/edit) your question and clarify what you are doing and what is going wrong, add your script so that we can help.

Comment: Well actually as mentioned, I just had a script that I inserted into the ROS file to be started when ROS is started at restart and the problem is that since it I cannot run any commands to stop the script since ROS is still running, I need another way to stop this scripts loop from running. I am not even in terminal yet since it doesn't go past ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to access it from other sources I found a way to switch between screens in Linux using: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (goes to <kbd>F6</kbd>).

This made it possible to log in as a user and re-edit the file / terminate the process.